# How to Terminate specific TCP sessions without tcpkill

Tags: linux, netstat

I found lot of TCP connections(listed through netstat) from my Linux server to windows server.

I want to kill those sessions without tcpkill cmd how can I ?

Please advise ..

Answer (score 2):

You could use iptables to block the outgoing connection. Grab the relevant remote IP (and if required port) from netstat then insert a rule into say the OUTPUT table to DROP the traffic for that host

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -d REMOTE_HOST -j DROP
```

or

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -d REMOTE_HOST -p tcp --dport 16387 -j DROP
```

Comment: I don't want to block the connection permanently.. Whatever the connection established right now I want close those connections .

Comment: Simply remove the block  a couple of minutes later.